# How to use tesseract ocr with php from any location

Tags: php, windows, wamp, ocr, tesseract

I have installed `tesseract` in **`C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR`**. In command prompt if I am executing with `tesseract 123.png sample`, then it works. But I can not use `tesseract` with `php`. I have tried many libraries and codes for the same.

Someone could help me on this please?

Comment: tesseract 123.png sample command works only on the tesseract installed folder through command prompt

Comment: What are the errors from PHP? There's like a million ways a command can fail in PHP. Provide proof of code of what you have attempted. Follow the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want a good answer and not a guess..

Comment: No errors are shown. The code i used is 

`if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/TesseractOCR/TesseractOCR.php';
 
 $file = dirname(__FILE__). '/upload/' . $_FILES['image']['name'];
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $file);
 
 $obj = new TesseractOCR($file);
 $obj->setTempDir(dirname(__FILE__).'/temp');
 $text = $obj->recognize(); 
 
}`



Github link:https://github.com/mepawan/phpocr-demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you needs to use Tesseract in php code, the way to do this is using the http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php functions, both allow you to execute bash codes like in "command prompt", but you needs to have more attention to use that, this open several security issues because the client input data sometimes is malicious. Hope it helps!

A working examples:

```
exec("tesseract C:/your/path/file.png C:/output/file");
```

Another thing, in part C:/output/file, you don't need to put .txt in output path, tesseract always do the output as .txt file extension.

If the Tesseract is not present on "Environment Variables" the solution is to pass the full executable file path:

```
shell_exec('"C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe" C:/path/to/image C:/output/path/')
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to use this exec() for tesseract service. I already tried different combinations with exec()

Comment: I tried
 `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
exec("tesseract E:/Documents/123.png E:/Documents/outtext");`
Unfortunatly it is not working and not showing any errors also. Anything else i need to do to access tesseract from any location?

Comment: Using your command, tesseract going to create a E:/Documents/outtext.txt file after execution.. Nothing is created? If not, maybe the problem is because tesseract is not defined as "Envrionment Path on Windows" this turns possible use the tesseract command in any directory via cmd, is Tesseract defined in Envrionment Path?

Comment: To test if he is enabled, open any directory in cmd and put "tesseract" and execute it, if windows recognize the command, all is ok, otherwise the command is not in "Environment Path".

Comment: Nothing created in that folder. i have added path in environment varible as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR`. Is this right one?

Comment: when i try `tesseract` from any directory it is showing result.

Comment: You have tested the command outside tesseract installation directory? If this test works, yes is ok.

Comment: Everything its looking ok.. Try to use shell_exec() insteadof exec()

Comment: no luck on that too.
i tired `exec("tesseract E:/Documents/123.png E:/Documents/Newfolder/outtext 2>&1", $output);`  and the output i got as  "Array ( [0] => 'tesseract' is not recognized as an internal or external command, [1] => operable program or batch file. )"... Any clue? if i am doing tesseract from same directory through cmd it shows results.

Comment: Unfortunately he is not recognizing the command, the problem is on this, but if works in cmd e not in the code, its strange.

Comment: Try to put the complete path of tesseract. `shell_exec('"C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe" E:/Documents/123.png E:/Documents/outtext')`

Comment: Wonderful, it worked. Thank you Bruno for you valuable time and suggestions. Please add this command also in your answer. i will mark it as the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: in some image the texts are note reading.any fine tuning method i need to do? it will support only some type of images? any extension limitations?

Comment: Exists some ways to optimize, take a look at documentation and the repository from tesseract https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract